# Is there a simple way to visualize/conceptualize how two electrons behave quantum mechanically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm just trying to develop a picture in my head for what happens when two quanta interact with one another. Say we had two perfectly localized electrons some distance apart, how does the wavefunction for the system "look" as time progresses.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this? https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlBGDw or maybe this https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WtfGDN ? This is my favourite visualization of a single electron wave function https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/gpu/schrodinger.htm

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. Since links may deprecate in the future, your answer would be greatly improved if you could give a description of the contents in each link.